# Окончание слова

Tags: окончания

*ООО "название" в лице директора ФИО согласнО/согласнЫ с условиями договора.*

Как правильно? Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Я убрал ваши лишние запятые.

Answer (score 1):

**Согласно**, поскольку общество — оно. Директор тут играет функцию олицетворения.